# Polymorphic Hierarchy DB Design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm looking for an efficient way to build a database model that can handle the following scenario:
The model needs to handle a hierarchy of undefined depth where each node can have 0 to 3 (at most) children where each child can be of one of 5-7 different types.

Below is an example of a sample tree that I need to support where 'foo', 'bar' etc. each would be entry in a different table and the number references the id from that table.  The assumption is that foo.1, bar.2, and foo.3 are the top level nodes.  Base is just a dummy object for me to point to the top level node of an unknown type.

```
Base.1
|-foo.1
  |-foo.2
    |-qaz.1
  |-bar.1
Base.2
|-bar.2
  |-qaz.2
  |-foo.2
  |-bar.3
Base.3
|-foo.3
```

Additionally, the order of the children must be maintained (i.e. it is not ok to switch qaz.2 with foo.2 in the above hierarchy).

From a data access perspective, most of the time I will be retrieving the entire tree inheriting from a top level object (Base.x).

The one thought I've had so far is to define a table with polymorphic association and each of the child node types reference that central table, such as:

```
BaseTable
---------
BaseId (PK)
ObjectId (FK)

ObjectTable
-----------
ObjectId (PK)
ObjectType
OtherTableId
BaseId (FK)   gets top level parent

FooTable
---------
FooId (PK)
Child1_ObjectId (FK)
Child2_ObjectId (FK)
Child3_ObjectID (FK)
Other data fields...

etc. for bar and qaz
```

My idea was that I could use the BaseID FK in the ObjectTable to grab the entire tree, but is there an efficient way to reconstruct the whole tree through SQL, or would I need to do that in my code after retrieval?  Or, is there a better way to store this kind of data in a way that is more efficient and guarantees relational integrity?

Answer (score 0):

> each would be entry in a different table

Is there a good reason for that?

Single Table Inheritance is the fastest, so if performance is your concern...

This will work:

```
create table foo (
  foo_id int primary key,
  type char(1) not null, 
  parent_id int null references foo(foo_id),
  display_order int not null default 0,
  foo_specific_data...,
  bar_specific_data...,
  qux_specific_data...,

  unique( parent_id, display_order )
);
```

Then use [recursive common table expressions](http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/02/trees-paths-recursive-cte-postgresql.html) to query (avoid MySQL/MaridDB). Use a trigger to enforce "max 3 children" rule / display order updates